# Azure Cloud Shell | remove app registration

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I'm trying to build a `cleanup` script that removes azure app registration from the cloud account.

From Azure documentation, I built a delete command but received an error.

I have the permission to remove the app registration manually, but the command failed.

The command that I ran:

```
Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "$appRegistryObjectId"
```

The error that I received:

```
Remove-AzureADApplication: Error occurred while executing RemoveApplication 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: requestContext
RequestId: 948d5c0c-e012-4ae8-b042-e6ae84ad4512
DateTimeStamp: Sun, 15 Oct 2023 12:31:29 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one Application in my environment like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/scLXyiW.png)]

To remove `Remove-AzureADApplication` ensure that you are passing correct `objectID` values:

```
$appRegistryObjectId = "2ea9b6aa-745b-41e5XXXXX"
Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $appRegistryObjectId
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/ZDOFwhW.png)]

[image]

In portal App removed successfully like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Remove-AzureADApplication (AzureAD) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0)

This error occurring if your account type is in `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`

[image]

Make sure to change `"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",` like below:

[image]

Now, when I ran the same code App removed successfully.

### Update

To can change `signInAudience: "AzureADMultipleOrgs",` and remove application using below command:

```c
# Define variables
$appDisplayName = "imranapp1"
$appSigninAudience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"
$appRegistryObjectId = "7d1655f1-9dbf-41fb-9906-xxxxx"

# Create an Azure AD application
az ad app create --display-name "$appDisplayName" --sign-in-audience "$appSigninAudience"

# Remove the Azure AD application
Remove-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "$appRegistryObjectId"
```

[image]

Now App registration change to `AzureADMultipleOrgs` and `removed Application` successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: It looks that something went wrong with your Update images

Comment: You need to change you manifest -> s`ignInAudience =  "AzureADMultipleOrgs"` like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Z8XXY7j.png) and run this script it will remove Application

Comment: Does it possible to change attribute during script? I'm trying to create a cleanup script

Comment: @omerblechman yes , it is possible check the updated answer and let me know

Comment: Thanks Imran, can I set the `signInAudience` for existing app registration as well?

Comment: Yaa i did on existing app registration only

Comment: But in your script, you are creating a new app registration. BTW the pictures are corrupted again

Comment: It was existing app reg given  vaules od existing appDisplayName  and appSigninAudience

Comment: As image was corrupted adding here again [image1](https://i.imgur.com/IpG2hYm.png) and [image2](https://i.imgur.com/IeC2GgK.png) check if it is visible.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Imran- *stop posting images of the documentation showing how to accept an answer*